# Error trying to access other system's camera by ssh within a python script

Tags: linux, ssh, python-3.x, camera, opencv

I am trying to access a live video from other system . for that i have copied a python opencv file in the remote system and i tried to access the video using ssh from my python script .

```
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.getoutput("ssh -X 192.xxx.yy.xx python36 /root/Desktop/vid.py")
"QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x25ea4d0) is not the object's thread (0x2aabfd0).\nCannot move to target thread (0x25ea4d0)\n\nQPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice"
```

How to solve this error and why this error has occurred?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you simply execute the `ssh` command by hand?

Comment: Same error even when I execute that ssh command from shell

Comment: Then it sounds like there's something wrong with the python script itself.

Comment: But when I run that vid.py script it runs perfectly in the system